# Change view query

Tags: views, database

I've a view and I would like to change it's query (slightly). Below is an example of what I have.

```
SELECT * FROM {node} node ORDER BY my_field ASC
```

I want to inject '***COLLATE utf8_danish_ci***' into query. My expectations below

```
SELECT * FROM {node} node ORDER BY my_field COLLATE utf8_danish_ci ASC
```

How would I do that in most correct way?

I'm also wondering if there is a way to apply such 'injection' only for specific view(s).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by altering view query as follow:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_query_alter
 * @param type $view
 * @param type $query 
 */
function <MODULENAME>_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {

  //simple example: change the order of the master display
  //if you want to do it only  on a certain display add something 
  // like  "&&$view->current_display == 'panel_page_1'"
  if ($view->name == '<VIEWMACHINENAME>') {

    //to find out what the fieldname ist: use devel and add your desired field as 
    //first filter ( =>orderby[0]). install devel and uncomment the next line
    //dpm($view->query->orderby)
    $view->query->orderby[0]['field'] = "{$view->query->orderby[0]['field']} COLLATE utf8_danish_ci";
  }
}
```

Add above code to your module, do necessary changes & clear cache.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, however it does not work. I tried that before as well.
Drupal does not allow to override [direction] with non allowed value (at the very end it is still just ASC, without my additions).
However I can change it to DESC or ASC (that works).

Comment: Drupal does not allow to put in 'direction' COLLATE or anything else. I think it has some sort of filter there (so only allowed values could be there).

Comment: If not in direction then try putting it in field as `$view->query->orderby[0]['field'] = "{$view->query->orderby[0]['field']} COLLATE utf8_danish_ci";`

Comment: Worked with field. Please update you answer with right information so I  can accept it as correct one. Here is my code I have at the very end

Comment: $n = count($query->orderby);
for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
  $query->orderby[$i]['field'] .= ' COLLATE utf8_danish_ci';
}

Comment: @Dmytro I have updated the answer.